# Snakemake runs rule too many times using config.yaml

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, transcription

I'm trying to create this snakemake workflow which would evaluate raw reads quality using FastQc and create a raport using MultiQC. I use 4 input files and get expected results, however I just noticed that each rule gets run 4 times and takes all 4 inputs each time and I'm not sure how to fix that. Could anyone help me figure out how to:

- Run the rule 4 times but use only one input from config.yaml at a time?
- Run the rule 1 time but use all 4 inputs?

I'm trying to follow the [snakemake tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html) but no luck so far.

**Snakefile:**

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
       expand("outputs/multiqc_report_1/{sample}_multiqc_report_1.html", sample=config["samples"])
        
rule raw_fastqc:
    input:
        expand("data/samples/{sample}.fastq", sample=config["samples"])
    output:
        "outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.html",
        "outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input} -o outputs/fastqc_1/"

rule raw_multiqc:
    input:
        expand("outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.html", sample=config["samples"]),
        expand("outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=config["samples"])
    output:
        "outputs/multiqc_report_1/{sample}_multiqc_report_1.html"
    shell:
        "multiqc ./outputs/fastqc_1/ -n {output}"
```

**config.yaml file:**

```
samples:
    Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R1_001: data/samples/Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq
    Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R2_001: data/samples/Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq
    KAPA_mRNA_HyperPrep_-UHRR-KAPA-100_ng_total_RNA-3_S8_L001_R1_001: data/samples/KAPA_mRNA_HyperPrep_-UHRR-KAPA-100_ng_total_RNA-3_S8_L001_R1_001.fastq
    KAPA_mRNA_HyperPrep_-UHRR-KAPA-100_ng_total_RNA-3_S8_L001_R2_001: data/samples/KAPA_mRNA_HyperPrep_-UHRR-KAPA-100_ng_total_RNA-3_S8_L001_R2_001.fastq
```

**I run the snakemake using command:**

```
snakemake -s Snakefile --core 1
```

**Each rule is run 4 times:**

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job            count    min threads    max threads
-----------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                1              1              1
raw_fastqc         4              1              1
raw_multiqc        4              1              1
total              9              1              1
```

**But each time all 4 inputs are used:**

```
[Sun May 15 23:06:22 2022]
rule raw_fastqc:
    input: data/samples/Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq, data/samples/Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq, data/samples/KAPA_mRNA_HyperPrep_-UHRR-KAPA-100_ng_total_RNA-3_S8_L001_R1_001.fastq, data/samples/KAPA_mRNA_HyperPrep_-UHRR-KAPA-100_ng_total_RNA-3_S8_L001_R2_001.fastq
    output: outputs/fastqc_1/Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R2_001_fastqc.html, outputs/fastqc_1/Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R2_001_fastqc.zip
    jobid: 3
    wildcards: sample=Collibri_standard_protocol-HBR-Collibri-100_ng-2_S1_L001_R2_001
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is using `expand()` in the input of each rule. Because `expand` fills in wildcard values, you only need to do that in the `all` rule since wildcard values are passed on to upstream rules.

Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
       expand("outputs/multiqc_report_1/{sample}_multiqc_report_1.html", sample=config["samples"])
        
rule raw_fastqc:
    input:
       "data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.html",
        "outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input} -o outputs/fastqc_1/"

rule raw_multiqc:
    input:
       "outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.html", 
       "outputs/fastqc_1/{sample}_fastqc.zip", 
    output:
        "outputs/multiqc_report_1/{sample}_multiqc_report_1.html"
    shell:
        "multiqc ./outputs/fastqc_1/ -n {output}"
```