# snakemake program not running all functions?

Tags: shell, snakemake

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
DATA = config['DATA_DIR']
BIN = config['BIN']
JASPAR = config['DATA_DIR']
RESULTS = config['RESULTS']
# JASPAR = "{0}/JASPAR2020".format(DATA)
JASPARS, ASSEMBLIES, BATCHES, TFS, BEDS = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(DATA, "{jaspar}", "{assembly}", "TFs", "{batch}", "{tf}", "{bed}.bed"))
rule all:
input:
    expand (os.path.join(RESULTS, "{jaspar}", "{assembly}", "LOLA_dbs", "JASPAR2020_LOLA_{batch}.RDS"), jaspar = JASPARS, assembly = ASSEMBLIES, batch = BATCHES)

rule createdb:
input:
    files = expand(os.path.join(RESULTS, "{jaspar}", "{assembly}", "data", "{batch}", "{tf}", "regions", "{bed}.bed"), zip, jaspar = JASPARS, assembly = ASSEMBLIES, batch = BATCHES, tf = TFS, bed = BEDS)
output:
    os.path.join(RESULTS, "{jaspar}", "{assembly}", "LOLA_dbs", "JASPAR2020_LOLA_{batch}.RDS")
    
shell:
    """
    R --vanilla --slave --silent -f {BIN}/create_lola_db.R \
    --args {RESULTS}/{wildcards.jaspar}/{wildcards.assembly}/data/{wildcards.batch} \
    {output};
    """
```

Why my snakemake program is not considering "createdb" rule. It is only considering "all". Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> "snakemake only runs the first rule in a Snakefile, by default." - [SOURCE](https://github.com/ctb/2019-snakemake-ucdavis/blob/master/tutorial.md)

If that first rule's input isn't clearly linked to `createdb`, it's not going to know to run `createdb`. Because the only rule it wants to run would have to depend on `createdb`.

I suspect your problem is the `input` to your rule `createdb` shouldn't have `expand()` used for all the wildcards already handled by rule `all`, just `bed`?. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72254110/8508004).
Also other avenues to consider for debugging is investigating what you unpacked `glob_wildcards()` to and what `files` is.