# snakemake tolerance for missing input

Tags: snakemake

In Snakemake, is there a built-in flag to tolerate missing input?

I have defined a Variable, say `CHR = [1,2,3,4,5]` and my starting point is one file of which multiple files could be generated (rule 1 -> file_1.txt ...file_5.txt). The idea is that rule 1 can generate one, some or all. For the downstream analysis I would like to expand over CHR without facing the error of input file is missing for rule X.
I have tried multiple approaches non seems to work:

- update CHR in rule and ensure the others follow -> still they used the original value only
- define a function that reads input from the folder -> directories and filenames are different according to the different rules (analysis) also file extension.
- making the input "directory" and the output dynamic -> in this solution I will have to loop within the loop over different files, which negates the purpose.

I'm including a simple case, in which I try to update the CHR:

```
CHR = [1,2,3,4,5]

rule all:
     expand("my_file_{chr}.txt", chr = CHR)


rule one:
   input:
     config["Inputfile"]
   output:
     config["outdir"] + "/rslts/rule_1/rule_1.csv"
   shell:
     """
      whatever
     """

rule get_CHR:
   input:
     config["outdir"] + "/rslts/rule_1/rule_1.csv"
   params: 
     outdir = config["outdir"] + "/rslts/update_CHR/", 
   output:
     config["outdir"] + "/rslts/update_CHR/update_{chr}.txt", 
   run: 
     chr_df = pd.read_csv({input}, sep=",")
     CHR = chr_df["chromosome_name"].tolist()
     shell(
     """
       while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line
       do
         echo ${{line[1]}} > {params.outdir}/update_${{line[0]}}.txt
       done < {input}
     """
     )

rule three:
   input:
     config["outdir"] + "/rslts/update_CHR/update_{chr}.txt"
   output:
     my_file_{chr}.txt
   shell:
    """ 
      whatever
    """
```

this example will work fine if all files existed, otherwise it fails.

I'm sorry if the issue is obvious, I've been trying several approaches today.

thank you

Comment: "this example will work fine if all files existed, otherwise it fails." It'd be nice if for your 'simple case' you indicated what all files would be. "I'm sorry if the issue is obvious" I may need more coffee today because as written it definitely isn't obvious. Your 'simple case' isn't so simple. I'm going to guess your second approach was along the right line of thought to pursue. You can make input functions that you then use to define the specific input based on what is there. You may want to keep in mind this brief advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72254110/8508004), that ...

Comment: <continued> states, "Your problem is using `expand()` in the input of each rule. Because expand fills in wildcard values, you only need to do that in the all rule since wildcard values are passed on to upstream rules." Another variation on that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73169073/8508004), "Don't be overwhelmed with rules and expands. At the end, rule all's input is a list of files you want. You can make that list with any valid python." Snakemake is actually a superset of Python and so you can pretty much bend it to your will using Python.

Comment: thanks for answering. I apologize if my example wasn't simple, I meant a simplified version from the actual workflow. I'm familiar with the approach in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251940/snakemake-runs-rule-too-many-times-using-config-yaml/72254110#72254110); I think what I'll do is create another config file on the run, with created samples, and call another snakemake instance within the first one, i.e. a smaller workflow to process the files, Since my main workflow will work with the resutls of merging and filtering these files once again. Thanks again

Comment: It seems like this is a use case for [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) since you cannot know ahead of time the output of a rule.